# Using HTTPS on several EC2 instances, with changing Public IPv4 DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have few EC2 instances (windows servers), and each of these instances has different images files.
For each of these EC2 instances, I have Public IPv4 DNS (which can change if I reboot the server).
My app, which need to read these images, knows the name of the image and on which server the image is located, so it can generate the image URL and read it. For example, it knows that the image is located on "server number 3", and the name of the image is "test.jpg", so it reads the image from http://ec2-54-174-155-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com/images/test.jpg
And if I add more servers or the domain of a server changes - I can simply updated the app's server list in a config file.
So far so good.

The problem is with HTTPS. I have no problem reading the images using HTTP, but I need to read it with HTTPS, and the default IPv4 DNS has no SSL.
I can't set subdomain and install SSL on each of these servers, because in case of heavy loads, I might need to add 30 more servers in 20 minutes.

So, how can I use HTTPS on EC2 servers, and still have the dynamic ability of adding and removing instances?
Maybe there's some kind of other AWS service I can use - route53, load balancer, or anything else - that allows HTTPS for EC2 instance, and I can also request content from a specific server under that service (remember - each EC2 server contains different files)?

Comment: You should really look into ECS and load balancing. Manually "knowing" on which server an image resides is not really feasible, how does that even work in theory? If you add 20 new servers they are just idle because everybody still "knows" that the 1000 interesting images that they want to load still reside on server 1, which means server 1 will still be under heavy load and new servers do not help. Where do the images originate from, where are they stored, where are they server from?

Comment: The images are generated by users.
Each user gets "his server" he communicates with, out of the existing EC2 instances array. There can be 5 instances in that array, or 20, or 50.
A single user doesn't "care" how many servers there are - he works only with his server.
Simple load balancing is not a good solution, because each server has different files.

Comment: Its not clear to me why you can't create ssl cerificate for the instances? You just create one wildcard certificate which will cover any subdomain that you create for the individual instances.

Comment: Because I need it to happen as fast as possible. If I want to add another 30 servers, I don't have the time to create subdomain for each and install SSL on each.